# Snap.svg How one can estimate size of SVG element without drawing?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Suppose, I want to calculate the position of elements on the `paper`(it's a term from [snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io)). I don't know the real size of my element due to it may depends of `CSS` styles, for example:

```
let text = paper.text(x,y,this.text).addClass("text");
let pos = text.getBBox();
let frame = paper.ellipse(pos.cx,pos.cy,pos.width,pos.height).addClass("frame");
let box = paper.group(text,frame)
```

The real size of the `box` evidentially is in relationship with `text` and `frame` styles. I have an algorithm to dispose ones in the paper, but it's needs width and height of boxes, but I don't know those before drawing.

The "dirty" solution is making an "invisible" `paper` and draw figures on it, but maybe it's possible do it in the right way?

Comment: I would draw an invisible `box` rather than the whole `paper` object. Have you tried using `getBBox();` with your `box`? Don't think it'll work but you could give it a try.

Comment: I think I can't draw `box` object without creation of `paper`, because my `box` is a group of `text` and `ellipse`, but `text` and `ellipse` methods are functions of `paper` object

Comment: Why can't you create a paper (assuming its not visible) ?

Comment: I can, but I suppose there is more elegant way to calculate dimensions of svg object.

Comment: @SergeySosnin Yes you need `paper` to draw your  `box`, but you can only make `box` invisible and see it's dimensions instead of the whole `paper`object.

Comment: drawing it invisible **is** the right way.